# Infinite recursion for 99 bottles of beer

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to print the lyrics to 99 bottles of beer, but, I get an infinite recursion, set on the first verse. Any ideas on how I can get rid of this infinite recursion?

```
    public static void bottlesOfBeer(int beer) { //prints the lyrics for "99 bottles of Beer on the wall".
        if (beer == 99) {
            for (beer = 99; beer > 0; bottlesOfBeer(beer - 1)) {
                System.out.println(beer
                    + " bottles of Beer on the wall!"
                    + beer + " bottles of Beer!"
                    + " Take one down, pass it around, "
                    + minusOneBeer(beer) + " bottles of beer on the wall!");
            }
        }
    }

    public static int minusOneBeer(int beer) {
        return beer - 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Were you trying to use iteration or recursion? It looks like you basically were confused and tried to use both.

Comment: I was attempting recursion

Comment: Just to give you a hint: your method will follow a form like `static void bottles(int b) { if(b > 0) bottles(b - 1); }` which will count down to 0.

Answer (score 2):

Yours isn't really a recursive approach to the problem.  Recursion would normally be performed *instead of* looping.  You have an odd mashup of recursion and iteration.

If your requirement is to solve the problem via recursion, then figure out how to do it without any loop construct (no, I will not do your homework for you).  You actually have most of what you need in place already.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think this is doing what you think it is doing. There is recursion **but** it only goes one layer deep. When you call `bottlesOfBeer(beer - 1)` this recursive call is guaranteed to not do anything because of the `if (beer == 99)` at the start of the method.

You will only enter that `if` statement if `beer == 99` therefore when you call the method again with `beer - 1` it will fail the if statement and end recursion.

What you are seeing is an infinite loop (different than infinite recursion) because no where in your `for` loop is the *local* copy of `beer` decremented. As such, the `beer` in the `for` loop will always be 99 and therefore the for loop will run forever.

You probably want something like this:

```
public static void bottlesOfBeer(int beer) {
    if (beer > 1) {
        System.out.println(beer
                + " bottles of Beer on the wall!"
                + beer + " bottles of Beer!"
                + " Take one down, pass it around, "
                + (beer - 1) + " bottles of beer on the wall!");
        bottlesOfBeer(beer - 1);
    }
    else if (beer == 1) {
        System.out.println(beer
                + " bottle of Beer on the wall!"
                + beer + " bottle of Beer!"
                + " Take one down, pass it around, "
                + " no more bottles of beer on the wall!");
    }
    else {
        // Do nothing if beer <= 0
    }
}
```

Comment: What's up with `else if (beer == 0) { System.out.println('go to the store and buy some more'); }`?

Comment: Not sure what you are referencing.

Answer (score 0):

look at your  `bottlesOfBeer(int beer)` method -

```
 public static void bottlesOfBeer(int beer)
```

it's return type is void. You use it in your for loop in as a placeholder of increment/decrement

Return some int from  `public static void bottlesOfBeer(int beer)` this method.

Hope it will help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK, the problem is that you never actually decrement beer. The correct way to do this is to replace the `bottlesOfBeer(beer-1)` portion with `beer--`. This will automatically decrement the beer every time the the loop runs its course.

This also means that the if(beer == 99) check can be removed. If you always want it to start from 99, make a constant called `BEERS_START = 99` and use that to initialize beers. If you want it to be able to start from an arbitrary integer, then just remove the check.

EDIT: 
Given that your teacher is requiring recursion, then you should handle the recursion in a different manner. I won't provide code, as I can't provide a good example without essentially writing your assignment for you. However, there is a much simpler way to do this than what you are doing. You do not need a for loop at all in this method. For that matter, you don't need the if statement either. Try designing the recursion without the for loop, and without the if statement. The end result will be much simpler once you get there.

If you're still having trouble after a bit of trying, post some updated code in the question, containing your new attempts, and let me know in another comment. I'll see if I can help from there.

Comment: That is how I had it initially, however, when I submitted it to the teacher (yes, I'm a student taking a course in Java), the teacher said that the "bottlesOfBeer" method needed to call itself.

Comment: @pati3ntzero OK, given your teacher's arbitrary requirement, I provided some more guidance in the answer. I can't give you code, as I would be essentially giving you the answer, but hopefully it points you in the correct direction.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public class HelloWorld {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    beers(3);

}

public static void beers(int n) { 
    if (n == 0){
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("No bottles of beer on the wall");
        System.out.println("no bottles of beer,");
        System.out.println("ya’ can’t take one down, ya’ can’t pass it around,");
        System.out.println("’cause there are no more bottles of beer on the wall!");
    } 
    else{
        System.out.println(n + " bottles of beer on the wall");
        System.out.println(n + " bottles of beer");
        System.out.println("Ya drink one down, pass it around,");
        System.out.println((n-1) + " bottles of beer on the wall");
        System.out.println();

        beers(n - 1);

    }
} 
}
```